# Search integer value using radiobutton

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I been searching for code but unfortunatelly I failed, So what better way than asking fellow coder. I dont know how to explain but here what I need. I want to be able to search using textbox associated with radio buttons. I can find anything that is related to STRING ut not integer...
Here is my code

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Public Class frmGuest
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow

```
Private Sub guestLoad()
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=admin;password=admin;database=gdatabases"
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from gdatabases.guest"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = Command
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bsource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub frmGuest_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    guestLoad()
End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet)
    If rdoReg.Checked Then
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("idguest like = {0}", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
    ElseIf rdoName.Checked Then
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
    ElseIf rdoNRIC.Checked Then
        DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(NRIC,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
    End If
End Sub
```

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYCMx.jpg)

Comment: For idguest just set rowfilter = 'idguest = ' & txtSearch.text

Comment: Column name idguest is correct? Also make sure it exists in data view

Comment: It is correct and exist in dataview. As I say, for string it is working such as the name..but not the idguest and NRIC. Do you have email so I can SC??

Comment: Please share some sample data in these columns and data type as well

Comment: Irfan, I add an image for refrence

Comment: Try the answer i posted

Comment: One more thing please verify that DataSet dbDataSet actually has data. Can you post the code to populate this dataset.

Comment: I have updated my solution. DataView takes a DataTable as parameter. Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "mysql"?

Comment: Andrew< I'm using Mysql as a database

Comment: Irfan, I repost my code...please check..tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
Dim DV As New DataView(dbDataSet.Tables(0))
If rdoReg.Checked Then
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("idguest = {0}", txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
ElseIf rdoName.Checked Then
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(Name,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
ElseIf rdoNRIC.Checked Then
    DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Convert(NRIC,'System.String') Like '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DV
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code work fine for Name and NRIC but not for the idguest

Comment: Actually i have tried for sample data with same column names and it works. now there is some information missing. Can you share some sample data?

Comment: Try to replace idguest with Convert(idguest,'System.String')

OR post a screenshot of table structure

Comment: Its working now...Thanks alot..Btw Irfan, I'm working on a system now, do you mind if I ask you some question if My code doesnt work??

Comment: Sure. Just post your question i will do my best to asdress it.